# Direct access to controller

Tags: config, controller

I'm trying to create a plugin with a controller, but I don't want to render any view but run a script from a cronjob. I can't get into the controller with an url and I'm not sure why.

I already tried everything [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers) but it does not state any way to directly call a controller with an url. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [that page in the docs says](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#how-controller-actions-fit-into-routing), dedicated controller action URLs will look like:

```
http://example.com/actions/pluginHandle/actionName
```

If your plugin’s name is “CocktailRecipes”, and you have a controller located at plugins/cocktailrecipes/controllers/CocktailRecipesController.php, and within that you have a function called `actionSaveIngredient()`, you would get to that via:

```
http://example.com/actions/cocktailRecipes/saveIngredient
```

If your controller is actually called CocktailRecipes_IngredientsController.php, it would be this instead:

```
http://example.com/actions/cocktailRecipes/ingredients/saveIngredient
```

Your plugin can also register a route (either [CP-facing](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerCpRoutes) or [site-facing](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerSiteRoutes)) which could provide a cleaner endpoint for the controller:

```
public function registerSiteRoutes()
{
    return array(
        'saveIngredient' => array('action' => 'cocktailRecipes/ingredients/saveIngredient'),
    );
}
```

If you had that in place, you’d be able to access CocktailRecipes_IngredientsController’s actionSaveIngredients() like this instead:

```
http://example.com/saveIngredient
```

**Note:** I don’t recommend trying to create a route for your controller until you’ve figured out how to get a basic action URL to point to it correctly. No need to add another step of complexity while you’re still troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4):

The docs explain how to [generate links to controller actions](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#linking-directly-to-controller-actions). Assuming your action trigger is "actions" (as it is by default) then your URL will look as follows:

```
http://www.domain.com/actions/pluginName/controllerName/actionName
```

Following the first example in the docs, the URL will look as follows:

```
http://www.domain.com/actions/cocktailRecipes/ingredients/deleteIngredient
```

Be sure to [allow anonymous access](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#allowing-anonymous-access-to-actions) to your controller action so it can be reached by the cron job.